# cron and wget: how to prevent cron from cluttering syslog with "grandchild failed" messages?

Tags: cron, wget, syslog, error-code

This is a huge annoyance.
Whilst in older `wget` versions (even stated so in the man page) the whole error code functionality had never worked reliably, current `wget` versions appear to have it working TOO reliably.

I have a `cron` job that might be dubbed a sort of "poor man's RSS", set up for a blog that has no RSS option. I'd just poll it every 15 minutes for new pages to come.
(that is, when it's currently at random-blog.net/entry2147.html, and I have 2148 stored in a variable and built my crontab from it, I will get `404`s UNTIL the entry2148.html page exists. (which is usually the case in less than 20 hours)

BUT...

`cron` tends to become a bit TOO verbose whenever `wget` returns a "not found" (404) (exit code 8):

```
(CRON) error grandchild #98765 failed with error code 8
```

Well I know that, don't I?! 
I know that page does not YET exist, but I do not need `cron` to tell me that with every run!
I've scoured the net for answers but there was nowhere any idea how to suppress these unnecessary messages while keeping my `syslog` tidy.

Unfortunately, there is no way to tell `wget` to simply output a code `0` despite "failure" (well, except for hacking it)

Any ideas about this problem, anyone?

Comment: Try putting an `exit 0` on the last line of your shell script.

Comment: @wildplasser You should probably put that as an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap the stuff inside a shell-script, that ignores the actual exit code and exits with a 0 return. It could look like:

```
#!/bin/sh

cd /home/me/mycrondir

wget -flags tralalala tweedledom  2>&1 >>/home/me/mycrondir/myerrorlog.log

exit 0
#Eof
```

If wget (or other binaries you need) is not in the $PATH (as provided by cron) you could add these at the top of this script, like

```
PATH=/opt/bin:$PATH; export PATH
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try that! And no, I'm not going to extend PATH just for that, I will simply call it as /usr/bin/wget or on another machine, /usr/local/bin/wget. crontab also allows me to use full paths doesn't it ;-)